# How to use @use in Bootstrap v5 instead of @import for customization

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, dart-sass

I'm trying to use @use instead of @import to import all the variables in my _custom.scss partial to styles.scss sass file. But @use is not overriding the variables as i intendent. How to solve?

***_custom.scss***

```css
 
$primary: #ff00f2;
$secondary: #bb6ef5;

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

***styles.scss***

```css
@import 'custom';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all the variables inside the with by using the @use as shown below

***_custom.scss***

```css
@use "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss" with (
$primary: 'your color';
$secondary: 'your color';
);
```

***styles.scss***

```
@use 'custom'
```